# PostgreSQL bulk insert with ActiveRecord

Tags: postgresql, activerecord

I've a lot of records that are originally from MySQL. I massaged the data so it will be successfully inserted into PostgreSQL using ActiveRecord. This I can easily do with insertions on row basis i.e one row at a time. This is very slow I want to do bulk insert but this fails if any of the rows contains invalid data. Is there anyway I can achieve bulk insert and only the invalid rows failing instead of the whole bulk?

Comment: MySQL being too tolerant have some not null columns with null data.

Comment: Wow. MySQL actually lets you do that? That's downright evil.

Answer (score 1):

#### COPY

When using SQL [**`COPY`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) for bulk insert (or its equivalent `\copy` in the psql client), ***failure is not an option***. `COPY` cannot skip illegal lines. You have to match your input format to the table you import to.

If data itself (not decorators) is violating your table definition, there are ways to make this a lot *more tolerant* though. For instance: create a temporary staging table with all columns of type `text`. COPY to it, then fix offending rows with SQL commands before converting to the actual data type and inserting into the actual target table.

Consider this related answer:
[How to bulk insert only new rows in PostreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834569/how-to-bulk-insert-only-new-rows-in-postresql/15834758#15834758)

Or this more advanced case:
["ERROR: extra data after last expected column" when using PostgreSQL COPY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367415/error-extra-data-after-last-expected-column-when-using-postgresql-copy/16367586#16367586)

If **`NULL` values** are offending, remove the NOT NULL constraint from your target table temporarily. Fix the rows after COPY, then reinstate the constraint. Or take the route with the staging table, if you cannot afford to soften your rules temporarily.
Sample code:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN col DROP NOT NULL;
COPY ...
-- repair, like ..
-- UPDATE tbl SET col = 0 WHERE col IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN col SET NOT NULL;
```

Or you just fix the source table. COPY tells you the number of the offending line. Use an editor of your preference and fix it, then retry. I like to use [`vim`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vim/info) for that.

#### `INSERT`

For an **`INSERT`** (like commented) the check for `NULL` values is trivial:

To skip a row with a `NULL` value:

```
INSERT INTO (col1, ...
SELECT col1, ...
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
```

To insert sth. else instead of a `NULL` value (empty string in my example):

```
INSERT INTO (col1, ...
SELECT COALESCE(col1, ''),  ...
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am not using copy am using insert with multiple values. Also using activerecord-activejdbc.

Comment: @zulq: I added solutions for `INSERT`. Note that `COPY` is *much* faster with lots of rows.

Comment: I am not doing insert into (col1,...) select. I'm using only insert into tablename(col,col2,col...) VALUES(set of values),(another set ofvalues),(another set of values) etc.

Answer (score 0):

A common work-around for this is to import the data into a `TEMPORARY` or `UNLOGGED` table with no constraints and, where data in the input is sufficiently bogus, `text` typed columns.

You can then do `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` queries against the data to populate the real table with a big query that cleans up the data during import. You can use a lot of `CASE` statements for this. The idea is to transform the data in one pass.

You might be able to do many of the fixes in Ruby as you read the data in, then push the data to PostgreSQL using `COPY ... FROM STDIN`. This is possible with Ruby's `Pg` gem, see eg https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/tip/sample/copyfrom.rb .

For more complicated cases, look at Pentaho Kettle or Talend Studio ETL tools.

Comment: It would be cool if Postgres had something similar as Oracle's `LOG ERRORS INTO...` clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, it would. Because of the way Pg works internally that'd require a `SAVEPOINT` for every row, though, and that'd be pretty horrifying from a performance point of view, plus it'd be a great way to get to xid wrap-around prevention vacuum in a huge hurry. Though if you disallow `AFTER` triggers it might work...