# How to store table with a large number of fields

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, dataset, multiple-columns

I'm working with a large dataset of human gene expression values throughout the full x, y, z MRI coordinates of the brain. Since there are ~60,000 genes in the human genome, and the researchers looked for the expression values of each gene in each of ~1000 samples that were taken, I need a way of storing a large number of columns in a database.

I am currently using a Node Module called pg for Postgresql with express, and I have 2 of my 3 tables set up already (tables 1 and 3 below). However for the second data set 60,000 is more than the number of columns that can be used in such a DB. I have considered using each gene (represented by a probe ID) as an entry in the table, and each of the ~1000 samples as columns, but I would have to create names for the columns with dynamically-assigned identifiers. In addition, using the genes as columns and the samples as entries seems to be the more logical way to organize the data.

Would a key-value store or a NoSql DB such as Mongo provide me with the ability to store more "columns" (~60,000 - one for each gene's expression) as properties of a "sample" schema/JSON object?

The available data consists of:

1. The Probes.csv file, which lists each Microarray probe's details such as its corresponding gene's name and the unique ID value for that gene (which I plan to use simply to map a text input of the gene's name, to the probe ID that is used in the other CSV files).
2. The ExprVals.csv file, which lists the expression values for each probe, currently listed with probe IDs as rows, and expression values as columns. These columns are ordered to match the order of the rows in the next file, which lists the coordinates of each sample for which the expression value was taken. (Above I mentioned that I would like to flip this table, so that the rows correspond to samples from the next file, and columns correspond to each probe ID, but I've not done this yet).
3. The Samples.csv file, which lists each sample with a unique sample ID, and the voxel coordinates of that sample, ordered to match the order of the columns in ExprVals.csv.

Thus, the queries that I would like to be able to make are:

1. A query of the Probes.csv table with a gene name, to get the ID values of the probes that correspond to it.
2. A query of the ExprVals.csv table with a probe ID, to get the list of expression values for that probe.
3. A query of the Samples.csv file for each listed expression value in the previous query, that returns the voxel coordinates of that that sample.

The end goal of this process is to be able to input a gene's name and get out a list of expression values for each voxel.

Comment: You don't need to store the data as either a 1000 x 60000 rectangle or a 60000 x 1000 rectangle.  You could instead store it as 60,000,000 tuples of the form `(gene,voxelid,value)`.  How to store the data depends on what kinds of queries you want to run, so please describe that.

Comment: Do you need to sort or filter on individual genes?

Comment: jjanes - So you are saying I should think about combining these separate tables into one longer one? This is an intriguing idea.

Comment: @jjanes PostgreSQL's large row header overhead will be an absolute killer for that, though. If the individual tuples are big enough the relative effect will be small, but if the tuples are small... ouch.

Comment: @CraigRinger  The overhead would certainly be significant, but I don't know if it would be fatal.  Someone who can run genechips on entire brain dissections presumably is not scrimping too much on the IO budget.

Comment: Do you have multiple donors, or is there just one donor for the whole project?  If multiple donors, is there one shared "map" from sample id to voxel coordinates, or is the map different for each donor?  Since people are different sizes, I would think the latter but maybe you have a way to normalize that.  You could always pack all the expression values and coordinates for a given (probe,donor) into one structure, like JSON, and store it in single field in PostgreSQL.  You couldn't efficiently ask "Expressions for all genes in this specific voxel", but you said that isn't your need.

Comment: There are six donors, but I'm currently only working with one of them, so a map isn't necessary at this point. I managed to generate field headers for the ExprVals dataset by following the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367415/error-extra-data-after-last-expected-column-when-using-postgresql-copy) question. 

Now I have all of the data I need in three different tables, but querying for a full list of ExprVals for a specified probe does take some time (~1 sec).

Comment: My next step is to create a model of the brain using Threejs that can have regions selectively highlighted by the data from the ExprVals table (based on a query of any particular gene's probe).